# BizTalk Schema Tracking issue

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2020

I am using BizTalk 2020 and BizTalk schema tracking is not working.

I checked the tracking settings under schema, however when I try to filter based on the schema name, no properties are shown.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Did make sure there Promoted Properties in your schema to track? (i.e. the correct schema version and/or Property Schema are deployed).

Comment: Checked multiple times..

Comment: Check that the pipelines used on the receive / send ports have tracking enabled.   Also did you process some messages after you made that change?